# <p:graphicImage> not working in jsf

Tags: jsf, primefaces, graphicimage

I recently included a `<p:galleria>` in my JSF page as shown in PrimeFaces showcase.
The code is executing without any errors, but it doesn't displaying any images. I think this is due to the incorrect path format for the images. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

`index.xhtml`

```
<p:galleria value="#{compa.images}" var="image" panelWidth="1570" panelHeight="250" showCaption="true">  
    <p:graphicImage value="resource/images/#{image}"  name="COMPANY CREATION"/>  
</p:galleria>
```

`compa.java`

```
public void init() {  
    images = new ArrayList<String>();  

    for(int i=1;i<=10;i++) {  
        images.add("resource/images" + i + ".jpg");  
    }  
}
```

The images path in IDE is `ps\build\web\resource\images`.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, JSF is in the context of this question merely a HTML code generator. In HTML, images are represented by the `<img>` element whose `src` attribute should point to a (relative) URL from which the webbrowser could download the image individually. Have you checked the generated HTML output by opening the JSF page in webbrowser and doing rightclick and *View Source*? Do the generated `<img>` elements look all right? Likely not.

The way how you used the `name` attribute is incorrect.

```
<p:graphicImage value="resource/images/#{image}"  name="COMPANY CREATION"/>
```

The `name` attribute represents the "resource name". It's basically the path to the resource, relative from the `/resources` folder on. This attribute has precedence over `value` attribute. So basically you're trying to create

```
<img src="COMPANY CREATION" />
```

This is not right. JSF would instead auto-generate a `RES_NOT_FOUND` URL. You should have seen that in the generated HTML output.

Provided that your intent is to show "COMPANY CREATION" as tooltip, then the right way is

```
<p:graphicImage name="images/#{image}" title="COMPANY CREATION" />
```

Or, if you insist in using `value` attribute, which takes a context-relative URL instead of a resource name:

```
<p:graphicImage value="/resources/images/#{image}" title="COMPANY CREATION" />
```